# CMake external static library circular dependency

Tags: makefile, cmake, circular-dependency

I am converting a Makefile to CMakeLists.txt in the GitHub project *[An implementation of Deformation Transfer algorithm in ANSI C](https://github.com/Golevka/deformation-transfer)*.

For example, in folder `/corres_resolve`, its Makefile is like the following.

```
INCLUDE_PATH    := ./ ../external/include/ ../common/
SOURCE_PATH     := ./ ../common/
DEPENDENCY_PATH := dep
OBJECT_PATH     := obj

EXTERNAL_LIBS := $(wildcard ../external/lib/*.a)
LDLIBS := -lm -lpthread

CFLAGS += -O3

include ../makefile.mk
```

Its makefile.mk is

```
vpath %.h $(INCLUDE_PATH)
vpath %.c $(SOURCE_PATH)
vpath %.d $(DEPENDENCY_PATH)
 vpath %.o $(OBJECT_PATH)

## Default .o and .dep path and program name
OBJECT_PATH     ?= obj
DEPENDENCY_PATH ?= dep
PROGRAM_NAME    ?= run

# Source trunk
source-files    = $(wildcard  $(addsuffix /*.c, $(SOURCE_PATH)))
source-list     = $(notdir  $(source-files))

# Binary trunk
objname-list    = $(subst  .c,.o, $(source-list))
object-list     = $(addprefix  $(OBJECT_PATH)/, $(objname-list))

# Dependency trunk
depname-list    = $(subst  .c,.d, $(source-list))
dependency-list = $(addprefix  $(DEPENDENCY_PATH)/, $(depname-list))

# -I option to help the compiler finding the headers
CFLAGS += $(addprefix  -I, $(INCLUDE_PATH))

# Build external library cmdline parameter, those -Xlinker directives instructs
# The linker find the correct linking sequence regardless the order of items
# specified in EXTERNAL_LIBS.`enter code here`
LOADLIBES += \
-Xlinker --start-group \
    $(addprefix  -Xlinker , $(EXTERNAL_LIBS)) \
-Xlinker --end-group

# PROGRAM_NAME is provided in custom makefile
$(PROGRAM_NAME): $(object-list)
$(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
$(OBJECT_PATH)/%.o: %.c
@mkdir -p $(OBJECT_PATH)
$(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
# Resolve [object,source] -- [header] dependency
-include $(dependency-list)
$(DEPENDENCY_PATH)/%.d: %.c
@mkdir -p $(DEPENDENCY_PATH)
@$(CC) -M $(CFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;           \
sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
rm -f $@.$$$$
```

Unfortunately, $(EXTERNAL_LIBS) has 10 static *.a files which have circular dependencies to each other.

How do I handle this in `CMakeLists.txt`?

Answer (score 2):

It shows in the `makefile.mk` file how to solve that with the `--start-group` and `--end-group` linker options.

With GCC, you would use `-Wl`, `--start-group`, and `-Wl`, `--end-group` around (only) the problematic libraries in your `target_link_libraries()`.